# Google calendar events returned with no start date nor end date

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I get events using php the standard way:

```
// get events

$events = $this->_service->events->listEvents($calendarId, $params);

// get each event and return an array of those
foreach ($events->getItems() as $event) { ....
```

The problem is that I have no "start" or "end" properties in my result on event which are not reccurring (which seems to be a special case).
The only params I send are time interval to retrieve the events + calendar id.

```
timeMin: '2016-10-28T00:00:00Z', 
timeMax: '2016-10-28T23:59:59Z'
```

Here is the object I get

```
anyoneCanAddSelf: null
attendeesOmitted: null
colorId: null
created: "2016-10-28T10:41:31.000Z"
description: null
endTimeUnspecified: null
etag: ""2955305459750000""
guestsCanInviteOthers: null
guestsCanModify: null
guestsCanSeeOtherGuests: null
hangoutLink: "https://plus.google.com/hangouts/xxxxx/another-meeting?hceid=bWNraW5zZXkudmlhZGly…"
htmlLink: "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=anVyNjd0OTk0cGs2c2px...
iCalUID: "jur67t994pk6sjqjf4nf66azdazdae98@google.com"
id: "jur67t994pkazdazdaz6sjqjf4nf66ae98"
kind: "calendar#event"
location: "8e Arrondissement, 75008 Paris, France"
locked: null
privateCopy: null
recurrence: null
recurringEventId: null
sequence: 0
status: "confirmed"
summary: "Another meeting"
transparency: null
updated: "2016-10-28T11:05:29.875Z"
visibility: null
```

I know the information I'm giving are not enough to know exactly what's happening here. But I'm just looking for some hints. I set this event through the calendar interface from 1pm to 2pm. Get the event but no duration (start/end properties).

If anyone encountered the same problem thank in advance for his help ! :)

Comment: Try to double check this event by using the [Try it](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/get#try-it) part in the [Events: get](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/get) and check if the result is the same without start and end date?